# How to add view option in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, action

I currently have allowed admins to delete a user by having

```
link_to("Delete", admin_path(resource), :confirm => "Do you want to delete this item?", :method => :delete)
```

How do I add the option for view, where I want someone to view that item?

Comment: option for view means? you want to show the user?

Comment: Yes....just the standard view button that shows details on a user.

Comment: link_to "Details of User", admin_path(resource) it will redirect to show action page where you can get the user details

Comment: I added link_to("View", admin_path(resource)) and I got nothing.

Comment: is there any action on controller

Comment: any link to provide for guidance on creating this?

Answer (score 1):

Rails applications typically respond to various actions based on HTTP verb, which routes to a method for that Controller.  The comments point out the correct code to link to the default show method for the Controller:

```
link_to("View", resource_path(resource))
```

However, you have to actually have a method written to retrieve and display the contents of the resource, including a template to display the fields, etc.

Comment: Do you have a link so I can have some guidance on creating this?